# React native multi select dropdown menu

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu, multi-select, textinput

I am new in React native. Lots of syntax are new to me. I want to make custom animated Multi-select dropdown menu. It will help me better understanding the native's syntax. I don't know which react native elements I should use `TextInput` or `flatlist` for that. My goal is make multi select dropdown menu like this image.
[image]

**PS**: I don't want to use library for that. It will not help me to understand how the react native's elements and its props work.

I will be glad if someone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want use library, let's refer `index.js` or another of library, you can understand how the react native's elements and its props work. [example](https://github.com/Eldjotnar/react-native-autocomplete-tags/blob/master/index.tsx)